# The server time zone value 'AEST' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, maven

I'm trying to setup a simple hibernate application, when I run it I get a stack trace full of errors.

I have the following maven dependencies in my `pom.xml` file:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

And the mysql version I'm running locally is:

```
5.7.9, for osx10.11 (x86_64)
```

I'm running, what seems, a very simple method, and still getting errors:

```
// create session factory
SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
            .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
            .addAnnotatedClass(Model.class)
            .buildSessionFactory();
        
// create session
Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

Model newModel = new Model("....", "...", "...");
        
// start a transaction
session.beginTransaction();
        
// save the student object
System.out.println("Saving the model...");
session.save(newModel);
```

After the above is executed, I get a long stack trace...The System.out.println doesn't print either...So the connection just doesn't seem to be connecting.

```
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Thu Jun 09 17:36:28 EST 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:723)
    at com.parkingapi.tests.Test.main(Test.java:17)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:19)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'AEST' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:695)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:663)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:653)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:638)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:606)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:624)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:620)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:68)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1683)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:656)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:349)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'AEST' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:54)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:73)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.util.TimeUtil.getCanonicalTimezone(TimeUtil.java:118)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.MysqlaSession.configureTimezone(MysqlaSession.java:308)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:2474)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:1817)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1673)
    ... 33 more
```

I'm focused on this error here:

> The server time zone value 'AEST' is unrecognized or represents more
> than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC
> driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more
> specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.

I'm unsure how I fix it?

###Edit:

Printing out the Timezone (System.out.println(TimeZone.getDefault());) prints the following details:

> sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Australia/Melbourne",offset=36000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=142,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Australia/Melbourne,offset=36000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=9,startDay=1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=1,endMode=3,endMonth=3,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=1]]

###Edit:

So I looked at the question which was flagged, and tried to change my connection string, but it's still throwing the same stack trace. Below is my new connection url. As you can see I changed the serverTimezone to that of the printed `Timezone.getDefault()`

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/parking_hib?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false;serverTimezone=Australia/Melbourne;useSSL=false;
```

Comment: Does it work with another connector like C oder ODBC?

Comment: Haven't tried? How would I test this out? @Michael-O

Comment: JDBC seems to be the most popular?

Comment: e.g., in PHP or Windows ODBC or unixODBC. What does the property `user.timezone` (`TimeZone.getDefault()`) on the client and server say?

Comment: You need a "real" time zone. The same happens with CEST ("Central European Standard Time") - here you have to decide on Europe/Berlin or Europe/Paris etc. For AEST this seems to be one of Australia/Sydney, Australia/Tasmania or Australia/Victoria.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change mysql timezone in java connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605953/how-to-change-mysql-timezone-in-java-connection)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/26515700/1809799

Comment: @René Seems to me like this could be a bug with the jdbc...As mentioned in one of the comments in that link, it doesn't 6.0.2

Comment: @James111 Have you tried Version 5.1.39 of the connector? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/6.0/en/connector-j-versions.html mentions version 6 to be a developer milestone ...

Comment: Was just trying that out before you commented...fixed the issue :) Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Turns out `6.x` wasn't compatible, moving to `5.1.39` fixed it.

Comment: Upgrading to 8.0.11 also fixes this.

Comment: Connector 8.0.15 seems broken and needs the above fix.

Comment: 8.0.23 by default uses the local timezone, and so does not have this problem by default either https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/8.0/en/news-8-0-23.html

Answer (score 96):

try to add those parameters..

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fussa?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

i'm using **mysql-connector-java 6.0.4**

Comment: This worked for me. I updated my Spring application.properties file. I'd like to set this to my local timezone though (Mountain Time) and would like it to be smart enough to handle daylight savings, (i.e., MDT becomes MST and back again throughout the year).

Comment: This parameter can be added to phpStorm database manager too to connect.

Comment: I updated my Linux server's /etc/localtime from /usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Pacific to /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles then restarted mysql service and this fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I had the same problem and this post solved it. Anyway, if I start application in debug mode, I have this exception: "Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server". Any idea?

Answer (score 23):

The proper solution, IMHO for AEDT, is to change the URL as follows,

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sampledb?serverTimezone=Australia/Sydney
```

Answer (score 6):

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fussa?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC
```

Use `&amp;` instead of `&`.

You can try change the timezone on mysql too:

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = '00:00';
```

And see the current setting:

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
```

Comment: @LawrenceDol actually you are incorrect. It is embedded in XML so still needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 4):

The exception is thrown because the MySql server timezone (inherited from the system timezone) is in a different format than what the mysql connector expects. You need to set MySql timezone to be 'Australia/Sydney'. Look at this awesome response for details: [Should MySQL have its timezone set to UTC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023978/should-mysql-have-its-timezone-set-to-utc/19075291#19075291)

- populate the mysql schema with the timezone information:

`mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql`

- from mysql run:

`SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'Australia/Sydney';`

- restart mysql server

Answer (score 4):

This is the problem of the version of the MySQLWorkbench. Upgrade to the latest version which is 8.0 and then add serverTimezone=UTC in your jdbc URL.

String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/your_db?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC";

Answer (score 2):

build.gradle >

```
compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.11'
```

application.properties >

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookworm?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

-

```
 mysql --version
 mysql  Ver 8.0.11 for osx10.13 on x86_64 (Homebrew)
```

This combination works for me.

Comment: Works for me, on SpringBoot with mysql 8.0

Answer (score 2):

Hi You need to specify in you URL specifier like below

```
        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jpahibernate?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC");
            dataSource.setUsername("root");
            dataSource.setPassword("Password");
            return dataSource;
        }
```

In the above code snippet have a look on `setUrl` property

Answer (score 2):

**In MySQL:** you may user bellow like:

1. **First solution:** add **serverTimezone=UTC** to connection url

   ```
   spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
   ```
2. **Second solution:** n MySQL **my.ini** file set **default-time-zone** value bellow like

   ```
   # Set default time zone
   default-time-zone = '+08:00'
   ```

Answer (score 1):

**Using default**

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/web_student_tracker?user=root&password=&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you using Spring Boot try to add after your localhost parameter a question mark and this:

```
?serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
```

So for example i have a mysql database with name: springboottutorial. In this example the param would be look like this:

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springboottutorial?serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, i was using  mysql-connector-java 8.0.15 (latest), but for some reaon it was still giving me a timezone error, i changed it for  mysql-connector-java 8.0.13 and that just did it. Hope thats be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by adding `"?serverTimezone=America/Los_Angeles"` right after the database name. I am from West Coast and my zone name is `"America/Los_Angeles"`. If you are not sure about your timezone name run below command on RHEL/UBUNTU/CENTOS

```
11:42 AM  ✔ user1 sfo-server1 Δ [~] Ω  timedatectl | grep "Time zone"
       Time zone: America/Los_Angeles (PDT, -0700)
```

Solution:

```
jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/movielens**?serverTimezone=America/Los_Angeles**"
```

Answer (score 0):

After loading the time zone data,

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'Australia/Sydney';
```

worked for me.

In my case, I wanted the setting to be persistent and none of these worked for me to persist the time zone and finally I went for the [option in mysql doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html) to set the start up parameter as below,

```
--default-time-zone=Australia/Sydney
```

The most common option was to set this in my.cnf and this didn't work for me, either.

NOTE: Mine is CentOS 8 & MySql 8

Comment: I need to contact you sir, need little help in CentOS. Could you plz DM me on Twitter @ankitmishraR or you give me something where I can talk to you.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using Docker, and need to configure this via an override, consider "hard coding" the TZ to make it unambiguous, eg:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    environment:
      - TZ=GMT+11:00
      # - TZ=Australia/Melbourne
```

Edit: actually, whilst this config doesn't throw an error any more, tomcat interprets the value correctly, whilst mysql interprets it as `GMT` :(

Answer (score 0):

edit /etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf on server section

```
[server]
default-time-zone = "Europe/Lisbon"
```