# i want to connect to db on java, but there is some errors

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
package dbb;

import java.sql.*;

public class test {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
        String user = "root";
        String pass = "1234";

        Connection conn = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("Driver Searched");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
            System.out.println("Connection Succeed" + conn);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Driver Not Searched");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

i made this code on java, but there are some errors.
for example,
[image].

It shows that Driver is already searched, but the connection is still failed.

How can i fix the error?

Comment: Add stacktraces as text not as image

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34189756/warning-about-ssl-connection-when-connecting-to-mysql-database

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515700/mysql-jdbc-driver-5-1-33-time-zone-issue

Comment: You can do the things suggested by the error log: use `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`; Disable SSL by adding `useSSL=false` to the url. The timezone value looks like something from a SSL handshake.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The server time zone value 'AEST' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37719818/the-server-time-zone-value-aest-is-unrecognized-or-represents-more-than-one-ti)

Comment: Which version of MySQL and which version of MySQL Connector/J. And please replace the image with the stacktrace as text.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
    String user = "root";
    String pass = "Admin@123";

    java.sql.Connection conn = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("Driver Searched");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
        System.out.println("Connection Succeed" + conn);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Driver Not Searched");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

it's working fine in my system with `mysql-connector-java-5.1.6jar`. Might be This is an issue with the `MySql` driver.

You can try with below :
you might need to explicitly specify timezone in you jdbc url.:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC";
```

Comment: Connector/J 5.1.6 is really ancient (it was released in 2008), the latest 5.1.x is 5.1.46 from March 2018, the latest version is 8.0.11 from last week (2018-04-19).

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested in the comment to use non-ssl connection with latest driver, you should use below code:

```
package dbb;
import java.sql.*;

public class test {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false";
    String user = "root";
    String pass = "1234";

    Connection conn = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("Driver Searched");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
        System.out.println("Connection Succeed" + conn);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Driver Not Searched");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: still there are problem!! HERE: java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value '´???¹?±¹ ???Ø½?' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.

Comment: Please share the stack trace.

Comment: SLL part is just warning

Comment: and this: Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value '´???¹?±¹ ???Ø½?' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.

Comment: Please refer to the URL provided [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515700/mysql-jdbc-driver-5-1-33-time-zone-issue?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa")[link]