# mysql-connector-java upgrade to 8.0.11 changes all the date values retrieved from the db

Tags: java, mysql

For a Spring project, the `mysql-connector-java` has been migrated from `6.0.6` to `8.0.11`.

Thus with `8.0.11` the problem is the following:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: 
The server time zone value 'PET' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. 
You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) 
to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
```

After to do a research

- [The server time zone value 'AEST' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37719818/the-server-time-zone-value-aest-is-unrecognized-or-represents-more-than-one-ti)

the solution is change the `URL` (I don't want return to a previous release)

- from: `mysql.jdbcUrl = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_v01?useSSL=false`
- to: `mysql.jdbcUrl = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_v01?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC`

Observe the addition of `&serverTimezone=UTC`

In my DB I have the following:

```
mysql> select * from persona;
+-----+--------------+-------------+------------+
| id  | nombre       | apellido    | fecha      |
+-----+--------------+-------------+------------+
...
| 088 | Something    | Something   | 1981-07-06 |
...
+-----+--------------+-------------+------------+
```

When the `Spring` application does a retrieve from the db through the `RowMapper<Persona>` I can confirm that `rs.getDate("fecha")` returns `1981-07-05` (observe the day has been decreased by one, it is **not** correct)

If the `mysql-connector-java` returns to `6.0.6` and thus `mysql.jdbcUrl = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_v01?useSSL=false` (**no** `serverTimezone=UTC`) `rs.getDate("fecha")` returns `1981-07-06` (how is expected)

Thus how fix this working with `8.0.11`?.

I want have the same behaviour when `serverTimezone` never was declared from the beginning, of course avoiding the exception.

Therefore the solution would be better if is take it in consideration that does not matter what value for `serverTimezone` was declared.

Answer (score 2):

There are several attributes related to timezone:

useTimezone:
Convert time/date types between client and server time zones (true/false, defaults to 'false')? This is part of the legacy date-time code, thus the property has an effect only when "useLegacyDatetimeCode=true."
Default: false

useLegacyDatetimeCode:
Use code for DATE/TIME/DATETIME/TIMESTAMP handling in result sets and statements that consistently handles time zone conversions from client to server and back again, or use the legacy code for these datatypes that has been in the driver for backwards-compatibility? Setting this property to 'false' voids the effects of "useTimezone," "useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift," "useGmtMillisForDatetimes," and "useFastDateParsing."
Default: true

serverTimezone:
Override detection/mapping of time zone. Used when time zone from server doesn't map to Java time zone

If mysql-connector-java is 5.1, you should specify three attributes, like this:
jdbc:mysql://host:port/dbname?useTimezone=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=true&serverTimezone=GMT%2B08:00

If mysql-connector-java is 8.0, you should specify one attribute, like this:
jdbc:mysql://host:port/dbname?serverTimezone=GMT%2B08:00

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=CST
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case the most unlikely suspect was **jackson**.

If your using Spring Boot add the following property to **application.properties**

```
spring.jackson.time-zone=Asia/Colombo
```

I've answered this with detail here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/68016006/9183199

Comment: I tried the same with a different timezone according my zone, it does not work always how is expected - so be careful