# How to set correct MySQL JDBC timezone in Spring Boot configuration

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hikaricp

DB:

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.27, for osx10.10 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Spring Boot: 2.1.1.RELEASE

The error:

```
2019-01-01 15:56:25.849 ERROR 39957 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
> :bootRun
java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'AEDT' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
```

Relevant parts of my properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/avmaint-local?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=#####
spring.datasource.password=########
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

What I find odd about this is that the error indicates that the timezone being used it AEDT, and yet I specified UTC in the `spring.datasource.url`. Does Hikari read something else when it initializes?

It does look very much like Hikari ignores the server timezone setting in the database url in favour of using my own machine's timezone which happens to be 'AEDT' (Melbourne, Australia) - This is unwanted behaviour. I would like Hikari to ignore my own machine's timezone. Does anyone know how to make it do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks for your answers, but I have found the solution.

As I suspected, Hikari ignores whatever you put in the datasource URL (so sorry guys, it doesn't matter what you chuck in there), essentially, it reads the timezone setting from MySQL itself, i.e., whatever the result you see when issuing the command:

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.time_zone;
```

in MySQL. In my case, the result was "SYSTEM", which is whatever my local machine it set at. This was AEDT, which is not supported by the MySQL driver and hence my exception.

Running this same query in AWS yielded the value "UTC", which is supported (and, actually what I wanted).

Therefore, I had to set the timezone in my local MySQL server.

Firstly, I had to load the available timezones from my host (Mac OS X) into MySQL. I had to find out where the zoneinfo file was (`/usr/share/zoneinfo` in my case) then find out out where the `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql' utility was (bin directory of the MySQL installation) and use it to load my local machine's supported timezones. In Mac OS X, I ended up running the command:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql
```

Then in MySQL I could run the command:

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = UTC;
```

this **is** a valid timezone, and is synchronized with the cloud based instances.

I think this is a real trap for a lot of people using MySQL with Spring Boot. It will work while people are in supported timezones, but if your development machine should switch to an unsupported timezone, it will quite mysteriously break, I'm surprised that it isn't documented anywhere. The source code of the MySQL Connector/J makes it obvious, but you wouldn't know it otherwise.

Maybe its because MySQL is just so 5 years ago, and I'm an old fossil and, and, well, just get off my lawn!

Answer (score 18):

Set `useLegacyDatetimeCode` false and set ServerTimezone.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/avmaint-local?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
```

Comment: thanks, but I tried that already - no effect whatsoever. As I mentioned, I don't think Hikari is looking at the connection string for timezone settings. Besides, I think the  `useLegacyDatetimeCode` workaround is mostly for Hibernate (which I'm not using)

Comment: I am using mysql 8.0.16, cannot start my spring boot app complaining time zone, so I tried the above settings and the app started.

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me. I set the variable in the db URL as such in `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?serverTimezone=America/Los_Angeles
```

Comment: This is the one that worked for me. Never thought of using that format for specifying the timezone! I used `Australia/Melbourne`

Comment: Great answer, if any one would like to use Zero Time Zone, set the value to
`serverTimezone=Etc/UTC`

Answer (score 6):

I added the following variable in the db url under `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?serverTimezone=GMT-6
```

and Spring Boot now runs ok.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using MySQL 8 and solved this question by injecting the value of the **user.timezone** property.

Using Java 8 in my project.

Relevant settings in appliction.properties:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mudi?serverTimezone=${user.timezone}
```

Using 2.3.4.RELEASE as parent project.

Dependencies used:

- spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf
- spring-boot-starter-web
- spring-boot-devtools
- spring-boot-starter-test
- junit-vintage-engine
- spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
- mysql-connector-java

HTH,

WB::

Comment: great stuff... out of all these answers i like this one best.

Answer (score 3):

Following Shaun it was enough for me with this:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/DEMOS?**serverTimezone=UTC**

Answer (score 2):

Set useLegacyDatetimeCode false is working for me. Thanks..

```
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee_directory? 
useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
```

Answer (score 2):

Using jdk 14, I had to do this to my `application.properties`

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibername.jdbc.time_zone=US/Michigan
```

edit: formatting

Comment: It solved the issue in the Spring boot version 2.1.6.RELEASE

Answer (score 2):

I've run into the same issue but adding

```
?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
```

after your schema name fixed this issue for me. Should look something like this

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my-schema-name?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
```

I'm currently using MySQL v8 and this works well for me.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to put into the file `application.properties` the next line:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC
```

It comes as an option in: https://www.baeldung.com/mysql-jdbc-timezone-spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

Add `useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false` to your connection string:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/avmaint-local?useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried 3 methods.

1. TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Colombo")); **// In Spring Initializer**
2. spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=Asia/Colombo **// In applications.properties**
3. <spring-boot.run.jvmArguments>-Duser.timezone=Asia/Colombo</spring-boot.run.jvmArguments> **// Setting property in POM file**

I also tried setting properties through JDBC URL;

- useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
- serverTimezone=Asia/Colombo

Non of the above worked for me. I noticed that the most unlikely suspect
**Jackson** was overriding my Timezone.

```
spring.jackson.time-zone=Asia/Colombo (The Answer)
```

Include this in you application.properties (it alone is enough)

Tested on Spring boot - 2.1.5.RELEASE , MYSQL8.

Answer (score 0):

When using SpringBoot dependencies, I recommend you not to use Hikari dependency by yourself. It is already inherited from SpringBoot.

When I added Hikari manually, I experienced very weird happening that on my local machine, timezone config (via jdbc string) doesn't work and remote machine in AWS has no problem.