# How to properly set timezone to UTC, so all timestamps are correctly saved and retrieved in this format?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

In my spring boot (2.1.4) project I have mysql database (5.7.21 - version of server) and following application properties:

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?serverTimezone=UTC`

and

`hibernate.jdbc.time-zone=UTC`.

Now when I save entitity records with `@CreationTimestamp` using java (either by using `@PostConstruct` or some controller/service logic) the dates are correctly converted to `UTC` timezone and saved do database, and also retrieved in `UTC` format (as I want them to be). However, when I add (other) records through `data.sql` file. The corresponding timestamp fields have also UTC timezone, but this time the time is not properly converted to UTC (it's just my current time with timezone set to UTC).

**How to properly set it for both situations to always convert local time to UTC, save it and always retrieve it as UTC from database?**

**Should changing mysql global timezone fix the issue?**

Example:

I am in timezone: GMT+2
The records saved at 11:11:53 have following time set for:

1.) Java created records:     09:11:53

2.) data.sql created records: 11:11:53

Both are in UTC timezone (I can see it, when fetch in client), but only first is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting global timezone to UTC fixed the issue (all timestamps are now set to **UTC**, display in my **local time** in database, but get retrieved as **UTC** from database), what satisfies my conditions and is unified for both `java` and `data.sql` origin records.

To do it on windows I had to download timezones sql file from here:
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html

,and run:

```
mysql -D mysql -uroot -pmypassword < timezone_posix.sql
SET @@global.time_zone = UTC;
```

Also this post helped me a lot:

[How to set correct MySQL JDBC timezone in Spring Boot configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53993181/how-to-set-correct-mysql-jdbc-timezone-in-spring-boot-configuration)