# Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-..:2.1.8. An exception occurred while running. null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc, java-ee-8

I'm new into SpringMVC and got stuck here.
I created a Spring Boot application through Spring Initializr and then
created `HomeController`, connected it with `index.jsp`. It was working
fine but when I added `SearchController`, connected with `search.jsp`, it
dosen't work now. Before adding `SearcController`, the application was
running fine but then it says:

**Failed to execute goal ...plugin:2.4.0:run (default-cli) on project hplus : Application finished with exit code: 1**

**Update**: after doing some searches I found out that my database's server
was not running and after running that, and running my application as
Test, I  got this error.

**Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when
'hibernate.dialect' not set**
.

```
Full Error!
Test set:HplusappApplicationTests
<<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

.

```
pom.xml file ->
<code>
xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
    instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
  https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>spring-example</groupId>
<artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>myapp</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties ->

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hplus
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

Comment: Without knowing wy it fails (i.e. the full error or test failure) it is impossible to answer this question.

Comment: @M. Deinum I have no idea how to find the whole and error and that's what I'm looking for.  
But the console says:  **Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.0:run (default-cli) on project myapp: Application finished with exit code: 1**

Comment: Run with debug information or just run things in your IDE.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, I could debug and find the full error, there I posted it on top.

Comment: That isn't the full error. That is indicating you are running without a proper task.

Comment: I thin now I found the error, just updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**
After searching for more than two days, I found out it's the timeZone problem.

I edited application.properties, line two ->

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hplus?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56537473/14623694

It solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
```

It clearly says that you entered a wrong `mvn` command. **What is the command you executed?**
We generally run `mvn clean install` to build an application.
Here is a list of [Maven commands](https://www.journaldev.com/33645/maven-commands-options-cheat-sheet) that might help you.

Comment: **'hibernate.dialect' not set**
You have to add `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect` in properties it seems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the MySQL dialect Hibernate should use :

put this in application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be error's when defining the bean and also your pom file, have you tried running a clean instal, with the

```
mvn clean instal
```

command? If that still doesn't work try to look at your pom and application.properties file is there still some mixed versions? If that still doesn't work try deleting your .m2 file and run the mvn clean install once again.