# What are JDBC-mysql Driver settings for sane handling of DATETIME and TIMESTAMP in UTC?

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, jdbc

Having been burned by mysql timezone and Daylight Savings "hour from hell" issues in the past, I decided my next application would store everything in UTC timezone and only interact with the database using UTC times (not even the closely-related GMT).

I soon ran into some mysterious bugs. After pulling my hair out for a while, I came up with this test code:

```
try(Connection conn = dao.getDataSource().getConnection();
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {

    Instant now = Instant.now();

    stmt.execute("set time_zone = '+00:00'");

    stmt.execute("create temporary table some_times("
            + " dt datetime,"
            + " ts timestamp,"
            + " dt_string datetime,"
            + " ts_string timestamp,"
            + " dt_epoch datetime,"
            + " ts_epoch timestamp,"
            + " dt_auto datetime default current_timestamp(),"
            + " ts_auto timestamp default current_timestamp(),"
            + " dtc char(19) generated always as (cast(dt as character)),"
            + " tsc char(19) generated always as (cast(ts as character)),"
            + " dt_autoc char(19) generated always as (cast(dt_auto as character)),"
            + " ts_autoc char(19) generated always as (cast(ts_auto as character))"
            + ")");

    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("insert into some_times "
            + "(dt, ts, dt_string, ts_string, dt_epoch, ts_epoch) values (?,?,?,?,from_unixtime(?),from_unixtime(?))");

    DateTimeFormatter dbFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));

    ps.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(now.toEpochMilli()));
    ps.setTimestamp(2, new Timestamp(now.toEpochMilli()));
    ps.setString(3, dbFormat.format(now));
    ps.setString(4, dbFormat.format(now));
    ps.setLong(5, now.getEpochSecond());
    ps.setLong(6,  now.getEpochSecond());
    ps.executeUpdate();             

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from some_times");
    ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();

    while(rs.next()) {
        for(int c=1; c <= md.getColumnCount(); ++c) {
            Instant inst1 = Instant.ofEpochMilli(rs.getTimestamp(c).getTime());
            Instant inst2 = Instant.from(dbFormat.parse(rs.getString(c).replaceAll("\\.0$", "")));
            System.out.println(inst1.getEpochSecond() - now.getEpochSecond());
            System.out.println(inst2.getEpochSecond() - now.getEpochSecond());
        }
    }
}
```

Note how the session timezone is set to UTC, and everything in the Java code is very timezone-aware and forced to UTC. The only thing in this entire environment which is not UTC is the JVM's default timezone.

I expected the output to be a bunch of `0`s but instead I get this

```
0
-28800
0
-28800
28800
0
28800
0
28800
0
28800
0
28800
0
28800
0
0
-28800
0
-28800
28800
0
28800
0
```

Each line of output is just subtracting the time stored from the time retrieved. The result in each row should be `0`.

It seems the JDBC driver is performing inappropriate timezone conversions. For an application which interacts fully in UTC although it runs on a VM that's not in UTC, is there any way to completely disable the TZ conversions?

i.e. Can this test be made to output all-zero rows?

*UPDATE*

Using `useLegacyDatetimeCode=false` (`cacheDefaultTimezone=false` makes no difference) changes the output but still not a fix:

```
0
-28800
0
-28800
0
-28800
0
-28800
0
-28800
0
-28800
0
-28800
0
-28800
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

*UPDATE2*

Checking the console (after changing the test to create a permanent table), I see all the values are STORED correctly:

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 27148
Server version: 5.7.12-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> set time_zone = '-00:00';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM some_times \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       dt: 2016-11-18 15:39:51
       ts: 2016-11-18 15:39:51
dt_string: 2016-11-18 15:39:51
ts_string: 2016-11-18 15:39:51
 dt_epoch: 2016-11-18 15:39:51
 ts_epoch: 2016-11-18 15:39:51
  dt_auto: 2016-11-18 15:39:51
  ts_auto: 2016-11-18 15:39:51
      dtc: 2016-11-18 15:39:51
      tsc: 2016-11-18 15:39:51
 dt_autoc: 2016-11-18 15:39:51
 ts_autoc: 2016-11-18 15:39:51
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: What's the DB and version of it? Also what JDBC driver are you using and version? (relevant since I already saw some Oracle bugs related to these kind of things)

Comment: mysql 5.7.12, JDBC Driver 5.1.40

Comment: Then say that in the question. It's important information. And tag it `mysql` too.

Comment: @AlexR Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7610174/1166537

Comment: See connection property [`cacheDefaultTimezone`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) (since 5.1.35, default: `true`): *Caches client's default time zone. This results in better performance when dealing with time zone conversions in Date and Time data types, however **it won't be aware of time zone changes if they happen at runtime**.* Oops! You're changing time zone as runtime with the `set time_zone = '+00:00'` statement.

Comment: I knew about `useLegacyDatetimeCode`, see updated question.

Comment: `cacheDefaultTimezone` parameter makes no difference.

Comment: Try the [`setTimeStamp()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp(int,%20java.sql.Timestamp,%20java.util.Calendar)) overload that takes a `Calendar` as an argument and specify the UTC TZ to the `Calendar` you pass in.

Comment: hi @MickMnemonic, the times are already stored in the DB correctly (see UPDATE2), so I'm afraid using `setTimeStamp with UTC TZ Calendar` might produce the expected output but for the wrong reason: storing the wrong value in the DB so that the incorrect conversion on the retrieval fixes it.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read your post that thoroughly. Maybe try the reciprocal method, [`ResultSet.getTimeStamp()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Calendar)) that takes in a `Calendar`?

Comment: Looking carefully at the output, the wrong results are coming from `getString()` not `getTimeStamp()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to set JDBC connection parameter `noDatetimeStringSync=true` with `useLegacyDatetimeCode=false`. As a bonus I also found `sessionVariables=time_zone='-00:00'` alleviates the need to `set time_zone` explicitly on every new connection.

There is some "intelligent" timezone conversion code that gets activated deep inside the `ResultSet.getString()` method when it detects that the column is a `TIMESTAMP` column.

Alas, this intelligent code has a bug: `TimeUtil.fastTimestampCreate(TimeZone tz, int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int seconds, int secondsPart)` returns a `Timestamp` wrongly tagged to the JVM's default timezone, even when the `tz` parameter is set to something else:

```
final static Timestamp fastTimestampCreate(TimeZone tz, int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int seconds, int secondsPart) {
    Calendar cal = (tz == null) ? new GregorianCalendar() : new GregorianCalendar(tz);
    cal.clear();

    // why-oh-why is this different than java.util.date, in the year part, but it still keeps the silly '0' for the start month????
    cal.set(year, month - 1, day, hour, minute, seconds);

    long tsAsMillis = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(tsAsMillis);
    ts.setNanos(secondsPart);

    return ts;
}
```

The return `ts` would be perfectly valid except when further up in the call chain, it is converted back to a string using the bare `toString()` method, which renders the `ts` as a String representing what a clock would display in the JVM-default timezone, instead of a String representation of the time in UTC. In `ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(int columnIndex, boolean checkDateTypes)`:

```
                case Types.TIMESTAMP:
                    Timestamp ts = getTimestampFromString(columnIndex, null, stringVal, this.getDefaultTimeZone(), false);

                    if (ts == null) {
                        this.wasNullFlag = true;

                        return null;
                    }

                    this.wasNullFlag = false;

                    return ts.toString();
```

Setting `noDatetimeStringSync=true` disables the entire parse/unparse mess and just returns the string value as-is received from the database.

Test output:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

The `useLegacyDatetimeCode=false` is still important because it changes the behaviour of `getDefaultTimeZone()` to use the database server's TZ.

While chasing this down I also found the documentation for  `useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift` is incorrect, although it makes no difference: documentation says [*This is part of the legacy date-time code, thus the property has an effect only when "useLegacyDatetimeCode=true."*], but that's wrong, see `ResultSetImpl.getNativeTimestampViaParseConversion(int, Calendar, TimeZone, boolean)`.