# Spring: Setup MySQL Database in Project

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I try to include a MySQL-DB in my project.

I've installed MySQL program, created a DB (schema) and set password and username for the access-authentification.

Included pom-file dependencies and so on.

Now I'm stuck with my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/asndb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=asnTeam1
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

In the MySQL Manager I can see all properties from my models, so the connection should work, right?

What do I wrong? Do I need the MySQL client?

**UPDATE** changed application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/asndb?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=asnTeam1
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.datasource.platform=mysql
spring.datasource.schema=schema-mysql.sql
spring.datasource.data=data-mysql.sql
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
```

Now I want to open with MySQL client my data.sql file. But there are erros in my sql syntax. Following an insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO USER (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD, USER_ROLE) VALUES('Admin', 'Istrator', 'admin', '$2a$10$W9xQIwa/FstPUvcbzJXnQ.XjVdTyIcCEp.g6VCq1gYuSsQNjJjbJG', 'ADMIN')

INSERT INTO USER (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD, USER_ROLE) VALUES('Bernd', 'Menia', 'bernd', '$2a$10$6dQcayeT/JAFvgFvzIjlcew5z9cmdCrGlv57.BGnIKvPXTDsQm7hG', 'PARENT')
INSERT INTO PARENT (FAMILY_STATUS, LOCATION, POSTCODE, STREET_NAME, IMG_NAME, STATUS, ID) VALUES ('MARRIED', 'Innsbruck', '6020', 'Bahnhofstraße', 'john.jpg',TRUE, SELECT ID FROM USER WHERE USERNAME = 'bernd')
```

What do I wrong?

***SOLUTION:***

insert the larger application.properties from above and for a persistent DB comment out the `ddl-auto=true` and `initialize=true` after the first spring-boot.

`User` is a reserved keyword in MySQL, so it is not allowed to use.

to fill a mySQL DB with data.sql file from spring-app is not possible, so I open the file via MySQL-Workbench and execute the statements.

Comment: what is the error ? Please add the stack trace

Comment: updated my question with the error message

Comment: @akuma8 added some information to my question above

Comment: it seems like the issue comes from timezone configuration. This can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605953/how-to-change-mysql-timezone-in-java-connection or this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605953/how-to-change-mysql-timezone-in-java-connection

Comment: thx.. made an update to my question ..

Comment: Install MySQL Workbench, it'll be easier for you to manage your database. Beside that, add the database name with each insertion. Something like  : 
`INSERT INTO asndb.USER(....)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142101/discussion-between-steveohio-and-akuma8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Came across to a similar problem from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27276523/7004388). Hope this helps.

Instead of

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/asndb
```

Try this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/asndb?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

Comment: thanks that helps.. but now there are no data from my data.sql in the DB anymore

Comment: try to add some data into your DB using mySQL commands from your console and check it.

Comment: it doesn't work. when i re-execute the SFW-statement the table is empty. I tried to open my data.sql file but it says there are errors in my sql syntax ... details above in the question

Comment: `user` is a reserved keyword in SQL. So, you can't use that as a table name. Create a table with another name like `user_table`. 
Check this Link - https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/list-of-sql-reserved-words
@SteveOhio

Answer (score 1):

To insert data in your database tables, be sure that the database is opened, so in your MySQL client, begin by :

```
mysql>use asndb;
```

And check that your tables : `user` and `parent` realy exist :

```
mysql>show tables;
```

After that you can insert your data :

```
INSERT INTO asndb.USER(.....);
```

And `USER` you can't use it