# The server time zone value 'CEST' is unrecognized

Tags: mysql, timezone, lamp

I am using hibernate (Hibernate Maven 5.2.15.Final, Mysql-connector Maven 8.0.9-rc) whith mysql 5.7 on lampp environment on linux so.

I am in Italy (Central European Summer Time) and once March 25, occurs follow error on connection db:

> The server time zone value 'CEST' is unrecognized or represents more
>   than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC
>   driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more
>   specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.

On mysql console, I ran:

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'time_zone';
SET GLOBAL time_zone='Europe/Rome';
```

but that did not persist.

Then I added to `my.cnf` file (in /etc/mysql):

```
[mysqld] 
default-time-zone = 'Europe/Rome'
```

and also:

```
default_time_zone = 'Europe/Rome'
```

but the db server did not start still...

Why does the error occur? 
Could someone help me?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to change that in your my.cnf file. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19069310/643039)

Answer (score 33):

@aiman's answer is not correct since in your case the effective server timezone is **not** UTC.

You'll find on the net some solutions including additional parameters on the jdbc connection string, but there are cases where you cannot change this string.

Here's how I fixed it:

First import the system timezones in mysql:

```
$ mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql
```

Then set your default mysql server timezone in the `[mysqld]` section of `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` (or of `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` on recent Debian/Ubuntu distros) to your actual server timezone, for instance:

```
default_time_zone = Europe/Paris
```

and don't forget to restart mysql

```
$ sudo service mysql restart
```

(or the appropriate command depending on your distro).

Comment: just in case someone has this problem on Windows, this worked for me to import the timezones into MySQL: follow the instructions to download an SQL file here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time-zone-support.html#time-zone-installation and execute `mysql -u root mysql < timezone_posix.sql`

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Any other answer I searched online are either changing time zone (!!!) or changing in the connection string, what is sometimes impossible to change. THANK YOU!

Comment: mysql 8 on ubuntu will not start with this `[ERROR] [MY-010361] [Server] Fatal error: Illegal or unknown default time zone 'Europe/Paris'`

Comment: After restart you should check, what is the timezone. `SELECT @@global.time_zone;`. If you see SYSTEM there, this means the change didn't work. I had set as root aDB user explicitly `SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'Europe/Stockholm';` and then I could connect with hibernate.

Answer (score 18):

If the problem is when connecting to the db, I found the solution in the NOTE of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7610174/2581587).

In your connection url use the following:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb?serverTimezone=Europe/Rome";
```

This worked for me to connect with flyway and timezone Europe/Amsterdam.

Comment: It worked for me. Note that serverTimezone=CEST doesn't work but Europe/Rome does.

Comment: Yeah, I believe that is because CEST is not specific enough, plus the S stands for Summer time, so you would tell the server/db it is set to summer time no matter the time of year.

Comment: Thanks a lot that works for me by changing  Europe/Paris

Comment: Thanks a lot that works for me by changing Europe/Berlin

Answer (score 14):

First see your mysql server timezone:
`mysql -e "SELECT @@global.time_zone;" -u <mysqluser> -p`.
Most probably it should be `SYSTEM`.
Find your system timezone: `date +”%Z`.
See if its CEST.
You need to change your system timezone:

```
#cd /usr/share/zoneinfo
#ls -l
#rm /etc/localtime
#ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC /etc/localtime
```

Then restart your mysql server: `/etc/init.d/mysqld restart`.

Enjoy

Comment: Had to use "systemctl restart mysql" to restart, but all other commands saved me :)

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me as well after trying with no success other solutions. Adding an info for the ones that might face the same problem i had: I got a "permission denied" while trying to execute the commands "rm /etc/localtime" and "ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC /etc/localtime". I've solved it adding "sudo" in the beginning, ex: sudo rm /etc/localtime.

Comment: So you change your actual timezone, which is CEST, to UTC, which is not your time zone. This is not a solution, but rather a dirty workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This cropped up out of the blue on my dev machine - restarting MySQL fixed for me