# MySQL Connector Java 8.0.18 - Time Zone is unrecognized

Tags: mysql, jdbc, timezone

I am working on upgrading existing libraries in our code and mysql-connector-java is one of them. We currently use the version: 5.1.25, I am trying to upgrade it to the latest version which is 8.0.18. I got some errors regarding to package structure changes but I've corrected them.

When I run the application (directly goes go database for authorization) I get following error:

```
The server time zone value 'CEST' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
```

After some research I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515700/mysql-jdbc-driver-5-1-33-time-zone-issue) question and realized I have to specify server time zone. Our database both on development and production environment configured as CEST time zone but when I add "serverTimeZone = CEST" to connection string I get following error:

```
No timezone mapping entry for 'CEST'
```

If I specify like "serverTimeZone = UTC", it works but confuses me also.

Why should I say UTC even though it is CEST? Time zone in my local system is UTC, is it the reason that I have to force it to UTC? If so, we have users all around the world, so bunch of request from different time zones will come to the DB server, if I say serverTimeZone = UTC, isn't it going to be a problem for them?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49518683/the-server-time-zone-value-cest-is-unrecognized

Comment: You could try specifying `serverTimeZone=Europe/Amsterdam` (or name for the zone in your area).

Comment: @user7294900 Hi, I've checked that post but suggestions were changing the time zone on the server which I am not allowed to do in the company.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Hi Mark, I still get the first error ( The server time zone value 'CEST' is unrecognized...) when I change it to Europe/Amsterdam. (That is the zone I am on)