# Does `serverTimezone` param change @@session.time_zone in MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, timezone

If I'm making a connection to MySQL with `serverTimezone=UTC` in my connection URL, will that change the `@@session.time_zone` variable for my connection to MySQL? Or is the only way to alter `@@session.time_zone` through issuing a `SET time_zone...` statement? I was lead to believe that the combination of `serverTimezone=UTC` and `useLegacyDateTimeCode=false` would set the `@@session.time_zone` to UTC (or whatever timezone I passed in as an argument to `serverTimezone`) but testing this behaviour with MySQL Connector/J seems to indicate it does not.

Comment: What does `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%zone%';` say on your server?  What version of MySQL and the Connector?  Is this relevant?  https://github.com/embulk/embulk-input-jdbc/issues/103

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem here. Have you managed to achieve the same behavior via JDBC driver configuration?

Answer (score 2):

As I said in a comment, I was facing the same problem -- needed to find a way of doing `@@session.time_zone = '+0:00'` without a SQL statement, by configuring the JDBC driver instead.

Here's the solution if you're using properties (Dropwizard and maybe Spring):

```
sessionTimeZone: UTC
useLegacyDatetimeCode: false
```

Or just append it to the JDBC connection URL: `?sessionTimeZone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false`

The connector's [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) doesn't mention it at all (and that's probably why there are so many answers pointing towards 'serverTimezone' and others.

Answer (score -1):

If you want your MySQL to be configured UTC :

```
SET @@global.time_zone = '+00:00';
```

So every automatic update of datetime and everytime you connect to the database, @@session.time_zone will be set to @@global.time_zone.

Reboot and reconnection of the DB could be needed.

If you're just interested by the modification of the timezone of your session :

```
SET @@session.time_zone = '+00:00';
```

You need to do this after every connection.

Comment: assuming that I have no control over the global timezone in MySQL (since there are many other systems using the same instance of MySQL, changing the global timezone may have unintended consequences), I am interested in managing the session timezone per connection. I know I can set it with a SQL statement, but I'm trying to find out if the `serverTimezone` URL parameter has any influence on the session timezone
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

Comment: That's good information but it doesn't really answer the question.