# I'm Not able to connect my Spring boot application to my database

Tags: spring-boot

Below you'll find the error

> java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'Paris, Madrid' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:76) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:835) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:455) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:179) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:119) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) [spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) [spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) [spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1821) [spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) [spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) [spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) [spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) [spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) [spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
> at com.example.BanqueSI.BanqueSiApplication.main(BanqueSiApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
> Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'Paris, Madrid' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
> at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
> at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:85) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
> at com.mysql.cj.util.TimeUtil.getCanonicalTimezone(TimeUtil.java:132) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
> at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.configureTimezone(NativeProtocol.java:2241) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
> at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.initServerSession(NativeProtocol.java:2265) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:1319) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:966) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
> ... 49 common frames omitted
>
> 2019-03-15 10:38:53.865  WARN 1708 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : The server time zone value 'Paris, Madrid' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
> 2019-03-15 10:38:53.876  INFO 1708 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
> 2019-03-15 10:38:53.892  INFO 1708 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
> 2019-03-15 10:38:54.033  WARN 1708 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.example.BanqueSI.Entities.Versement
> 2019-03-15 10:38:54.037  INFO 1708 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
> 2019-03-15 10:38:54.055  INFO 1708 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
> 2019-03-15 10:38:54.063 ERROR 1708 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.example.BanqueSI.Entities.Versement
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1762) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
> at com.example.BanqueSI.BanqueSiApplication.main(BanqueSiApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.example.BanqueSI.Entities.Versement
> at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.determineDefaultAccessType(InheritanceState.java:266) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:211) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:778) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:250) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:274) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1821) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
> ... 16 common frames omitted

Comment: It looks something wrong with your server and database timezone. Can you look on the following issue. It can help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605953/how-to-change-mysql-timezone-in-a-database-connection-using-java

Comment: Please add the relevant database configurations from your Spring Boot config file.

Comment: You have to be more specific on the problem you are facing.

Comment: I created a simple client app . i created a database in MySQL this is my application.properties configuration :

Comment: spring.datasource.url=spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/client_db
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=

server.port=8085

#Specify the DMBS
spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
#show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#hibernate ddl auto
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
#Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyComponentPathImpl
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver. though i still ihave the same error

Comment: Mr dunni I'm using Eclipse I don't know how to get the file u re asking for??

Answer (score 1):

Try these changes in the properties file. It works for me.

1.
Remove This property from application.properties file and try hopefully it works.

> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

2.
or Try this URL for connection String

> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/client_db?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, but with the only difference, that i live in Austria. I kind of solved this problem by changing the time zone in my sql server via the sql command line:

```
SELECT NOW();

SET GLOBAL time_zone = '-6:00';
```

The only problem with this solution is, that I have to change it over and over again. This happens, because by default and startup, the sql-server always refers to the timezone, configured on your pc or mac.

[This was my problem and solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66162204/is-there-any-way-for-solving-the-known-problem-in-spring-boot-when-connection-to)