# Change serverTimezone in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc

I want to change serverTimezone to GMT+3.
I try this but not working

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/example?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=GMT+3&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
```

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No timezone mapping entry for 'GMT 3'
```

but if I run this it is working with GMT-3

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/example?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=GMT-3&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
```

how can I change this to GMT+3 ?

Comment: Wht Mysql version do you use?

Comment: Particularly this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54003680/1615903

Comment: in a nutshell: since this is a URI, the `+` should be encoded to `%2B`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please Override PostConstruct in Main Boot App as below

```
@PostConstruct
public void init()
{
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));   
}
```

Replace Asia/Kolkata with your timezone

Comment: Setting the JVM default timezone is something entirely different from configuring the MySQL server time zone. Doing this could break applications that were built with a specific expectation with regard to the JVM default timezone.